# Url command with utf-8 url

Tags: livecode

I was trying to download a URL from the following address:

[http://data.riksdagen.se/personlista/?utformat=json&valkrets=Värmlands+Län](http://data.riksdagen.se/personlista/?utformat=json&valkrets=V%C3%A4rmlands+L%C3%A4n)

(Open Data from the Swedish government)

This works perfectly in the browser but using the `url` command in LiveCode doesn't quite as the Swedish character ä doesn't get encoded properly. I've tried to `urlEncode` the string but it still doesn't work. Is there any way to download a url with utf-8 encoded characters.

If I call `curl` via shell I do get the correct values, but that isn't available on the mobile...

Answer (score 1):

After some thinking and digging I realised that the answer is of course to translate the url from UTF-16 that LiveCode uses internally into UTF-8 that the server expects. The browsers use UTF-8 by default so thats why it's working there. So

```
put url "http://data.riksdagen.se/personlista/?utformat=json&valkrets=" & textEncode("Värmlands+Län", "utf8")
```

did the trick!
The problem is that I can't use the `urlencode`function as that translates all Swedish characters and the server expects them as UTF-8 (which is of course strange by itself!)

Comment: Verified here. UTF-8 would not need to be URL encoded because it's expressed in ASCII compatible characters, assuming the server expects UTF-8, as this one does.